# Strange behavior of Spring Data Elasticsearch with a Wildcard query using a '?'

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

I created a Spring Boot application using spring-data-elasticsearch 5.1.1. When I execute my query on the database, I get the correct result, but not with the API, and I can't figure out why.

I have an Elasticsearch database that has an index "users" configured like this:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "country": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "firstname": {
                "type": "keyword"
            },
            "lastname": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
    }
}
```

When I execute the query: GET http://localhost:9200/_sql?

```
{
    "query": "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE 'Micka_l' and country = 'FR' LIMIT 100"
}
```

I get the user Mickael.

And when I modify the query:

```
{
    "query": "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE 'Mick_l' and country = 'FR' LIMIT 100"
}
```

I don't get any results because I removed a letter in 'Mick_l'.

By executing the query: GET http://localhost:9200/_sql/translate, I retrieved the generated query to use in my Spring Boot Service:

```
    public List<UserDTO> searchUsers(SearchDTO searchDTO) {
        // Equals 'FR'
        String country = searchDTO.getCountry();
        // Equals 'Micka?l' ou 'Mick?l'
        String firstname = searchDTO.getFirstname();

        StringQuery queryString = new StringQuery("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"term\": {\"country\": " +
                "{\"value\": \"" + country + "\"}}},{\"wildcard\": {\"firstname\": {\"wildcard\": \"" + firstname + "\"," +
                "\"boost\": 1.0}}}],\"boost\": 1.0}}");

        SearchHits<User> searchHits = searchOperations.search(queryString, User.class);

        List<User> userList = searchHits.getSearchHits().stream().map(SearchHit::getContent).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return userList.stream().map((user) -> UserMapper.MAPPER.mapToDTO(user)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

This query allows me to search for users by their first name like this:

POST http://localhost:8080/api/user/search

```
{
    "country": "FRA",
    "firstname": "Micka_l"
}
```

Returns: Mickael

But:

```
{
    "country": "FRA",
    "firstname": "Mick_l"
}
```

Also returns: Mickael, whereas I need the search to be case-sensitive. Why does the "?" behave like a "*"?

I have tried several approaches with JPA:

```
List<User> findByCountryAndFirstnameLike(country, firstname)
```

And also with @Query:

```
@Query("{\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"term\": {\"country\": \"{\"value\": \" ?0 \"}}},{\"wildcard\": {\"firstname\": {\"wildcard\": \" ?1 \","\"boost\": 1.0}}}],\"boost\": 1.0}}")
List<User> findByCountryAndFirstnameLike(country, firstname)
```

The behavior is the same.

Have you ever tested this behavior?

I tried one last approach with NativeSearchQueryBuilder(), but I can't finish the configuration:

```
    public List<UserDTO> searchUsers(SearchDTO searchDTO) {

        String country = searchDTO.getCountry();
        String firstname = searchDTO.getFirstname();

        TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery.Builder().field("country").value(country).build();
        WildcardQuery wildcardQuery = new WildcardQuery.Builder().value(firstname).caseInsensitive(true).boost(1.0F).build();

// Doesn't Work:
        NativeSearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                .withQuery(new BoolQuery.Builder()
                        .must(t -> t.term(termQuery))
                        .must(w -> w.wildcard(wildcardQuery))
                ).build();


        SearchHits<User> searchHits = searchOperations.search(searchQuery, User.class);

        List<User> userList = searchHits.getSearchHits().stream().map(SearchHit::getContent).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return userList.stream().map((user) -> UserMapper.MAPPER.mapToDTO(user)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

I'm not sure if this approach can resolve the unexpected behavior when using a "?".

Comment: where in your query do you use a "?"?

Comment: But you don't use legit ? or * in your wildcard query. You use _ - according to YOU. Would be great if you clarify the mess first.

Comment: In SQL '_' is equivalent to '?' and '&' equals '*' with elasticsearch. Using localhost:9200/_sql, elasticsearch translates the query itself.

Comment: When I use Spring Boot my SearchDTO object contains country = 'FR' and user = 'Mick?l' or 'Micka?el' and the result should be different from 'Mick*l' because directly with elasticSearch the result is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your first approach to generating elasticsearch queries is opening you for code injection attacks. I hope you are not doing something like this in production code. Anyway, there is a lot in your question - SQL, JQuery, Spring Data, it seems to be all over the place. So let's start with the backend. In elasticsearch, everything works as expected:

```
DELETE test

PUT test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "country": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "firstname": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "lastname": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{}}
{"firstname":"Mickael", "lastname": "Carreira", "country": "PT"}
{"index":{}}
{"firstname":"Mickael", "lastname": "Landreau", "country": "FR"}

// Returns one record
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "country": {
              "value": "FR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "firstname": {
              "wildcard": "Micka?l",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}

// Returns no records
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "country": {
              "value": "FR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "firstname": {
              "wildcard": "Mick?l",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Let's now figure out which query your code generates and which part doesn't work.

BTW, `"boost": 1` doesn't do anything so we can simplify it to

```
// Returns one record
GET test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "country": {
              "value": "FR"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "firstname": {
              "wildcard": "Micka?l"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, removing "boost": 1 solved my problem. http://localhost:9200/_sql/translate suggested I add '"boost": 1.0' but it's not necessary.